# Исходный код страницы в переменную

Tags: php

Есть скрипт который загружает исходный код страницы (с удаленного сервера) в переменную и ищет в нем определенную строку.
Раньше это скрипт работал для сайта vk.com, решил им сейчас воспользоваться он чего то не пашет. Он не получает исходный код от сервера. Подскажите пожалуйста что с ним можно сделать чтобы он работал.
Заранее спасибо!

```
$online = "<b id=\"profile_online_lv\" class=\"fl_r\">Online<b";
$nid = ;// id страницы нужной личности * id0000
$file = fopen("http://vk.com/".$nid,"rt") or die("Ошибка\n"); 
while(!feof($file))
    {
        $string = fgets($file);
        if(strpos("$string","$online")!=false) $hid=1;
    }
fclose($file);

//Выводит собщение о статусе в брвзер
if ($hid == 1)
    {
        echo " Онлайн<br>";
    } else {
        echo " Офлайн<br>";
    }
```

Данный скрипт работает на других сайтах кроме VK.com

или

как исходный код (html) странички пр.(http://vk.com/pr_artemm/) занести в переменную. для дальнейшей работы с содержимым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эмулируйте заголовки браузера, с помощью curl например.

Answer (score 0):

Задать переменную $nid = ;  я полагаю

Comment: причем здесь переменная $nid, я стер ее значение, дабы не указывать на конкретную страничку. Можно написать и так
    $file = fopen("http://vk.com/id1","rt") or die("Ошибка\n");    
только скрипт от этого скрипт все равно не заработает